# Error Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: json, excel, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that reads from an Excel file. It stores data from particular cells/columns, converts to JSON and then sends it via REST to my Wordpress install.

The issue I'm having is that when attempting to run the script using data taken from Excel, it presents the error

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

```bsh
#Declare the file path and sheet name
$file = "P:\file.xlsx"
$sheetName = "IN PRODUCTION"

###############################################
#                                             #
#             EXCEL FUNCTIONS                 #
#                                             #
###############################################

#Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible = $false

#Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count 

#Declare the starting positions
$rowName,$colName = 1,1
$rowSignOff,$colSignOff = 1,2
$rowReceived,$colReceived = 1,3
$rowBuildStart,$colBuildStart = 1,4
$rowBuildEnd,$colBuildEnd = 1,5
$rowShipping,$colShipping = 1,6
$rowBuiltBy,$colBuiltBy = 1,7
$rowQA,$colQA = 1,8
$rowCage,$colCage = 1,9
$rowComment,$colComment = 1,10
$rowStatus,$colStatus = 1,11

$build = @()

#Loop to get values and store it
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
    $name = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowName+$i, $colName).Text
    $signoff = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowSignOff+$i, $colSignOff).Text
    $received = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowReceived+$i, $colReceived).Text
    $buildstart = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowBuildStart+$i, $colBuildStart).Text
    $buildend = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowBuildEnd+$i, $colBuildEnd).Text
    $shipping = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowShipping+$i, $colShipping).Text
    $builtby = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowBuiltBy+$i, $colBuiltBy).Text
    $qa = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowQA+$i, $colQA).Text
    $cage = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowCage+$i, $colCage).Text
    $comment = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowComment+$i, $colComment).Text
    $status = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowStatus+$i, $colStatus).Text

    $build += [PSCustomObject]@{
        name = $name
        start = $buildstart
        end = $buildend
        by = $builtby
        notes = $comment
    }
}

###############################################
#                                             #
#              POST FUNCTIONS                 #
#                                             #
###############################################

$content = [PSCustomObject]@{
    staging_fields = @{
        staging_repeater=$build
    }
}


$json = $content | ConvertTo-Json -Depth $([int32]::MaxValue)
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json
Write-Host $json

#Close excel file
$objExcel.Quit()
```

The output of `Write-Host $json` is as below

```json
{
    "staging_fields": {
        "staging_repeater": [
            {
                "name": "Test 1",
                "start": "19/12/2016",
                "end": "09/01/2017",
                "by": "JM",
                "notes": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Test 2",
                "start": "01/01/2017",
                "end": "11/01/2017",
                "by": "JC",
                "notes": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Test 3",
                "start": "17/01/2017",
                "end": "01/02/2017",
                "by": "JM",
                "notes": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Pasting this into Postman and sending a POST request produces no errors and successfully adds to my WordPress site.

If it helps, the full error is below

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"code":"rest_invalid_json","message":"Invalid JSON body passed.","data":{"status":400,"json_error_code":5,"json_error_message":"Malformed UTF-8 
characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"}}
At L:\\Untitled1.ps1:98 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization=("B ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

If I were to replace the variables with strings such as "Test", the script works correctly. Below is an example.

```bsh
#Loop to get values and store it
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
    $name = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowName+$i, $colName).Text 
    $signoff = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowSignOff+$i, $colSignOff).Text
    $received = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowReceived+$i, $colReceived).Text
    $buildstart = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowBuildStart+$i, $colBuildStart).Text
    $buildend = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowBuildEnd+$i, $colBuildEnd).Text
    $shipping = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowShipping+$i, $colShipping).Text
    $builtby = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowBuiltBy+$i, $colBuiltBy).Text
    $qa = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowQA+$i, $colQA).Text
    $cage = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowCage+$i, $colCage).Text
    $comment = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowComment+$i, $colComment).Text
    $status = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowStatus+$i, $colStatus).Text

    $build += [PSCustomObject]@{
        name = "test"
        start = "test"
        end = "test"
        by = "test"
        notes = "test"
    }
}
```

It appears the data coming from Excel is not coming through with the correct character encoding. This is where I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have no idea on what value it is choking but I would first try to find the wrong value by first using "test" everywhere and change one by one until it throws. Once you've identified the field like that, I would start playing with the loop to know what row the invalid field is in.

Comment: Exactly what I just tried - it was indeed the very first $name variable picking up on Café in the excel document which I did not spot initially.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot.

Within the excel file, autocorrect had changed **cafe** to **Café** which was the cause of the issue. Simply renaming resolved this for me.

Comment: Good to have it solved but even better would be if you could sanitize the excel data somehow?!